# Spring Boot Themeleaf TemplateInputException : HTTP 500

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to deploy my spring boot application on aws ec2 instance and I am facing below error

[image]

No matter what I try it doesn't work. Below is the application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true 
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html  
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
```

The same configuration work fine in my IDE without any problem and have already tried few things from previous stack overflow tickets but none helped.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem, I am facing a similar issue